# Android 7" 800x480 tables unable to see my app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I've got this issue, some of the 7-inch 800x480 resolution low-end tablets cant see my app in Play Store. 
there goes my Manifest part

```
    <compatible-screens>

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

As I want to support only tablets, I didn't mention small and normal screens. Also had to do some special clauses for various versions of Nexus 7. Anyone ever heard of this issue? I'm pretty sure those tablets I mentioned before are somehow "normal" screen devices but I've got no clue how to fix this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="false"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="false"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Try these baby it will good to see your app ...

Comment: I dont want to support phone screens, and what youre suggesting is enabling smallScreens also

Comment: see the edited answer that will support most the tablet device configuration : Disable small and normal using false conditions will make it happen baby'